# robotext file pointing to a local sitemap

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt

Within a `robots.txt` file, would be possible to use a relative path instead of an absolute one for pointing out a Sitemap?

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

instead:

```
Sitemap: sitemap.xml
```

**Curiose note SO robots.txt**

```
#
# this technically isn't valid, since for some godforsaken reason 
# sitemap paths must be ABSOLUTE and not relative. 
#
Sitemap: /sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The official sitemap documentation](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php) shows a complete URL in its example of including a reference to an XML sitemap location.

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap-host1.xml
```

However, it does not specify whether or not a complete URL or absolute path must be used. The StackOverflow robots.txt implies that an absolute path is required and that they had issues when they used a relative path. So it is probably best to use a complete URL or absolute path if you want to be certain that search engines find your sitemap. Since this is very easy to do I don't see any reason why a relative should be used.

Comment: Thanks John for your answer. The reason for my question is: I use a custom CMS that can be used for many websites. I need the User have a out of box fully filled robots.txt with the right parameters without accessing the robots.txt file itself. Because every site has different URL a local path would be an easy solution. I understand your point so the best solution I think would be write the robots.txt file pro-grammatically.